# Postgres Process Suspended Windows 10

Tags: windows, postgresql, process, suspend

Good day I have a business automation system that uses the Postgres database.

I have a problem that is very common in my clients. I am using the 9.5 version of Postgres and "nothing" one postgres process is suspended and can no longer close it or return to normal, there the database lock, and only starts restarting the computer, a customer has times what happens to the bank continue working more does not accept a new connection. The seviço postgres is with the status Running, but not for no more restarts.

-already tried to change the Secondary Logon service to automatic and did not work.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question, really. This is more software trouble.

Comment: So it is possible to post programming questions here?

Comment: yes, but nothing of what you've posted has anything to do with programming.

Comment: I could show me where I can post this kind of question? I have a problem with this record, and I do not know what to do.

Comment: Maybe the DBA site. this sounds more like db administration in any case.

Comment: You should get a stack trace of the "hanging" process and post that. Do you know what the hanging backend is running? Are there any backends *idle in transaction*?

Comment: This is a great question, can a moderator please move it to the correct forum?